How to sparse pull from a repo while full push/pull to/from another?
I don't know if I am making things clear or not (since I am not an advances git user), so please ask follow up questions to better understand where I'm coming from.
Consider this repo: Void Linux official
This git repository is used to build Void Linux's packages in the official package repository. I cannot push/pull because they have strict rules on what packages can be added to their official repository. So I want to create my personal repository for me  and a few friends of me.
The void-packages stores build instructions in patches and templates for any package say alpine under srcpkgs/alpine/template. The other files like xbps-src and directories common and etc contains actual build scripts that looks at the templates and patches to build any package.
I want to pull all the commits from xbps-src, common and etc from the repository, but I don't want the templates for all the packages in srcpkgs because I do not need them and it is so huge that pushing and pulling takes a lot of time. So, I create a sparse pull like this:
git config sparsecheckout true
echo '/*' > .git/info/sparse-checkout
echo '!/srcpkgs/*' > .git/info/sparse-checkout

This is my origin remote pointing to the above github link. I created a personal repository which is my tilde remote and push only my changes (to srcpkgs along with upstream xbps-src and others):
git checkout master
git checkout --orphan temp
git add -A
git commit -m 'New orphaned commit'
git branch -D master
git branch -m master
git push tilde master

I do this because I didn't want to push all the srcpkgs packages from origin to  tilde repository and master had all the history. So, I orphaned master. Now say I create a new package say, srcpkgs/brave-browser/template and commit it.
git add srcpkgs/brave-browser/template
git commit -m 'Added Brave Browser'
git push tilde master

But this doesn't work because the sparsecheckout is completely ignoring my own commits. So, how do I do a sparse push/pull in origin while doing a full push/pull in tilde remote?

I am not sure I understand... particularly, I am not sure where it breaks.... not fully understand what you would like to achieve, say, the grand goal... so I will talk about the specifics that I have in front of me in the question. So... when you set the local master branch into the new single commit, this is a completely new history from what you had setup in tilde.... when you push your new masterinto tilde, you will have to force push... perhaps you are already doing that and it is not in the recipe...... there's at least one more comment coming.

I am lost in the last part of your recipe... so, you add something... and commit... I assume you are on the new local master branch.... and now you want to push this.... it should not fail if you force, because you are not missing anything... you would be pushing a full history of a branch.... or is it that you would like for this new work you have just done in the last commit to be setup on top of the work that is already in tilde/master?

Then.... I wonder why you want to separate the repo from what the upstream repo is/has.... having your own separate repository with whatever branches you want to keep from a project is perfectly fine.... you would keep the original master branch from the original void project in your repo... and then create separate branches for it for your private stuff..... having a completely new history will only introduce what I think are unnecessary headaches into your workflow.

You could use your local repo to push the upstream branch into your tilde branch: git fetch origin; git push tilde origin/master:master (which should not fail if you only keep in your tilde/master branch what is in origin/master)... and then you can freely add your stuff into separate feature branches that you will keep in your private repo... no need to have special permissions to pull it off.

That's not a sparse clone, you cloned everything. What you did instead was tell Git to entirely ignore the srcpkgs directory in your work tree, to never write to or read from it, so when adding you didn't add any of it. I suspect all the chatter from the rest of the files "added" in your orphan branch's first commit obscured the omission.
To avoid fetching content you don't ever need to look at, let alone touch, one way to do it would be add --filter=tree:1 --sparse to your clone, that'll set up cone-mode i.e. whole-directory-but-only-selected-ones sparsity rules and after cloning you can git sparse-checkout set xbps-src common etc srcpkgs/your-new-package to tell Git what (besides the toplevel files) you want to see; it'll fetch those on demand. Your new package doesn't exist yet but you need to tell Git you want it, since the default for "sparse" is you want Git to treat it like it doesn't exist.
When you fork a package on github the fork gets all existing history, which involves, exactly, no actual history duplication at all -- in much the same way as a local clone that doesn't cross filesystem boundaries involves no actual history duplication. There's more cost to making a completely new repo the way you did, anybody wants to fetch from a straight fork can avoid fetching things they don't want the same way you did.
So what you want instead is to just fork the upstream, do your fetching from there and pushing normally to your fork. It'll send only the objects that have changed since the last ancestor Git can see the upstream already has (or possibly aren't in any commit Git can see it and the upstream both have by checking the upstream's tips, I forget and it doesn't really matter here).
If you really really want a single-package srcpkgs directory you can git rm --cached srcpkgs/* immediately after your sparsecheckout add, before adding your new package.
There's a bunch more ways to do this, Git's operating on a simple underlying structure, its apparent complexity comes from all the things you can do with that structure and ways you can interpret it. I don't know what constraints you're operating under and which of them are negotiable, so best I do for now is the quick sample of possibilities here.
